# Питон, графика, окна произвольной формы без заголовка

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, tkinter, pygame

Есть ли возможность создать окно произвольной формы в библиотеках `pygame`, `pyglet`, `tkinter`? (ЯП питон)

Я долго искал, как создавать графические окна в питон, под форму картинки, но нашёл только про библиотеку `PyQt5`, которая всё время глючит. Но не может же так быть, что такая возможность есть только в этой библиотеке?!

Comment: `которая всё время глючит` - в 99% случаев у новичков на самом деле не библиотека глючит (или компилятор, например), а сам код.

Comment: Для самой проверки бралось примерно 5 кодов из интернета, включая примеры из учебников. Появлялось окно, положение которого никак не регулировалось, и ничто на него не выводилось.

Comment: И в чем глюк? Может это так и задумано было. Не зная, что это за примеры были, ничего конкретного нельзя сказать.

Comment: Я программирую на питоне уже год. И разобрать код длиной в 15 строчек всё таки могу. Тем более, когда в учебнике всегда разбирается, что именно делает код. Я точно знаю, что на windows такой проблемы не возникало. Но у меня linux, и изредка выявляются подобные глюки.

Comment: @Интик "звёздочкой окно не сделать" забыли добавить "средствами tkinter". На WinAPI такое точно можно сделать, думаю под Linux тоже возможно, может быть даже кроссплатформенно. Но вообще эту тему глубоко не копал.

Comment: @Интик  на `PyQt` можно реализовать практический все.

Comment: @insolor готов поспорить на xlib можно не меньше, чем на winapi для гуи (другое дело, что winapi это не только гуи).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, я плохо понимаю ваш вопрос.
Вернее я понимаю, что вам надо создать окно произвольной формы
используя библиотеках pygame, pyglet, tkinter.
Но зачем вы наговариваете на `PyQt5`, я совсем не понимаю.

Прежде чем запустить мой пример, убедитесь, что вы установили `PyQt5`

```
pip install PyQt5
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

`PyQt` — реализация фреймворка `Qt` для языка `Python`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

 
class Demo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png").scaled(
            350, 350, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.FastTransformation)

        pal = self.palette()
        pal.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Normal, QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtGui.QBrush(pixmap))
        pal.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtGui.QBrush(pixmap))
        self.setPalette(pal)
        self.setMask(pixmap.mask())

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('<h1 style="color: red;">Hello World!</h1>', self)
        label.move(80, 120)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Закрыть окно", self)
        button.setFixedSize(120, 30)
        button.move(90, 220)
        button.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit)

        self.offset = None
        self.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            self.offset = event.pos()
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove and self.offset is not None:
            self.move(self.pos() - self.offset + event.pos())
            return True
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
            self.offset = None
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

        
if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Demo()
    w.resize(350, 350)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему не PyQt5 и на счёт глюков. В ответ на запрос pip3 uninstall pyqt5 терминал сообщает, что библиотека и так не скачена. Но в ответ на запрос pip3 install pyqt5 сообщает, что библиотека уже скачена.

Comment: После запуска, например, Вашей программы в терминале вылезает сообщение qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin, и всё. Никакой графики. Qt графика в linux mint всё время глючит, поэтому был вопрос, можно ли повторить необходимый функционал в любой другой библиотеке.

Comment: Не обязательно именно такая постановка вопроса. Вы знаете экранного жителя - Винни Пуха на воздушном шарике? Он рисуется поверх всех окон, никак не мешая просмотру, и не является отдельным графическим окном. И у меня возник вопрос, как это повторить.

Comment: Ведь теоретически, должна быть возможность вывода изображения в определённые координаты экрана, без создания отдельных графических окон?

Comment: @filkar2005 возможность всегда есть. а то что вы не можете установить PyQt5, не означает, что библиотека PyQt5 всё время глючит.

Comment: Так библиотека установлена, интерпретатор не выдаёт ошибок при запуске, библиотека подключается, как видно из сообщения компилятора, а дальше - всё.

Comment: А на счёт возможности вывода изображения поверх всех окон - это и была изначальная цель. Но не нашёл как.

Comment: Очень классно. У меня похожий magic 8 ball был ;D

Comment: @filkar2005 Блин это легко исправить! Просто запусти: `sudo apt install python3-pyqt5`. Разве в гугле не было этого? ;) Извини, но любой маломальский линуксоид должен это знать!

Comment: А почему на скриншоте некрасивая чёрная обводка? Будь я нубом, я бы по этому поводу тоже объявил «pyqt5 глючит» )

Comment: @andreymal и это ваше право делать такие объявления.